# List Index out of Range while scraping over multiple weeks

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been trying to web scrape Billboard's top 100 charts weekly from 1958 to 2021 but I'm having a problem. I want to get the name of the song, artist, how many weeks it has been on chart and the year of every #1 song in the top 100 chart from August 1958 until July 2021. I've defined a function to get that info for a given link (of a particular week) and then I use a for loop to repeat the process for every week (I've stored every week's link of the period in a list) but I get Index Error: list index out of Range while doing so. All the sites have the same HTML structure so I think the problem is not there but I've been repeating the for loop and I don't always get the same info from the sites (i.e I may get until 1960 and on another try I might get info until 1975) so that confuses me. If anyone has an idea of what may be the problem and wants to help me I'd appreciate it. Here goes the code:

```
base_url = "https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/{}"

start_date = datetime(1958, 8, 2)
end_date = datetime(2021, 7, 10)
one_week = timedelta(days=7)

links = []
while start_date <= end_date:
  url_ = base_url.format(start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
  links.append(url_)
  start_date += one_week

song = []
art = []
weeks = []
year = []
dicc = {'Song': song, 'Artist': art, 'Weeks_on_chart': weeks, 'Year': year}
def getdata(url):  
    r = requests.get(url, headers= headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    song.append(soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'chart-element__information__song text--truncate color--primary'})[0].get_text())
    art.append(soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'chart-element__information__artist text--truncate color--secondary'})[0].get_text())
    weeks.append(soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'chart-element__meta text--center color--secondary text--week'})[0].get_text())
    year.append(soup.find_all('button',{'class': 'date-selector__button button--link'})[0].get_text().split()[2])

for element in links: #repeat for every link (every week)
  getdata(element)    #here is where List index out of Range pops (lists from function getdata)


df = pd.DataFrame(dicc)
df #just to visualize until which year I could get info
```

Comment: You're probably got captcha page. Try to reduce the rate of crawling, for example with `time.sleep`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to index a list without checking if the list is empty or not. You'll have to rewrite getData() to ensure that when you make you calls  soup.find_all() you aren't getting an empty list and handle that error how you want when you do. Also ensure you the elements you want to access are on the you are parsing.